# what can I do if my email is broken into parts for imap in php? MIME header

Tags: php, gmail, imap, mime-types

I have an email. The body has 2 parts, one part is the message which is ASC something content type

then in the body I have signature which has content type utf-8 with header MIME version 1. The message body doesnt have a MIME header but the signature in the body end does. So when I use imap to retrieve the emails, the message doesnt show but the signature does. any idea what I can do to fix this? Every email by default generally has content type utf with MIME header, emails such as gmail, yahoo, msn etc all have it. We are using an exchange server 10 years old so I dont know of the settings as I am the coop student.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need a mime parser for php, similar to http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/